# Rails - Store 'service range' for restaurants, allow users to search for restaurants who service their zipcode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding

I'm looking for a way, with Rails, to search on a restaurant's delivery range.

For example, I have a Restaurant model that stores a location and miles willing to travel.

Visitors to the site give their zipcode in a search field, and if their zip code is within a restaurant's delivery range, that restaurant is returned as a search result.

I'm currently using the geocoder gem, which doesn't seem to have a way to save a range or radius around a given point. I can search for "restaurants within 5 miles of my search location," but not for "restaurants whose delivery range includes my visitor's search term."

I'm a n00b, so anything that involves SQL/another language is probably not doable. I'm hoping there's some kind of logic hack... like loop around each one of my restaurants, see if the .nearby result includes my visitor's search zipcode.

Also, apologies if this has been asked before. I didn't see anything specific to Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to go solely off of zip_codes you could have a distance table that mapped the distance between two given zip codes.  It'd be like a many-to-many table with itself. The ID could be the zip code and you could have a method like.

```
def distance_to(zip_code)
  # Find row where two zip_codes are defined and the saved distance
end
```

But I don't know if this is something you necessarily want to hold in data.  For a couple reasons, one being that the area someone lives in for a zip code varies and thus that distance is not consistent.  Finally, there are so many things you could use that do this already.

You may then want to consider looking into a maps API. Google, Bing, OpenStreetMaps or some other mapping service with a decent api and just put in the coordinates and the distance given back can determine whether or not your user is in range.

This way you handle edge cases and you no longer have to worry about storing that data either. It also preps you for a greater level of precision if needed.